# How a download user checks md5 after file download?

Tags: download, md5, md5-file

We may notice many download sites provide md5 string. For example, when I download *ABC.zip*, along with an md5 string like: “`2743a6a9fe6f873df1c7ed8ac91df5d7 *ABC.zip`”. I know the idea behind it, it’s Digest algorithm to prevent file forge.

My question is how a user calculates md5 string for the *ABC.zip*, and compare it with value site provides? Any existing tool to generate md5 string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends a bit on your operating system ofcourse. Under most Linux/Unix distributions you have an `md5` or `md5sum` program available.

Example:

```
# md5sum eclipse-SDK-3.6RC3-linux-gtk.tar.gz
8eca528d2c0b33dae10ba8750b2e4b94  eclipse-SDK-3.6RC3-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```

It also has a check mode which does exactly what you're looking for:

```
# md5sum -c test.md5
eclipse-SDK-3.6RC3-linux-gtk.tar.gz: OK
```

(test.md5 has the output of the previous command)

Comment: @卢声远 Shengyuan Lu: Wikipedia has some links to Windows versions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum#External_links
There isn't really a standard program for Windows, but you can install the Linux ports or something graphical like `flashsfv`: http://www.trvx.com/flashsfv/

Comment: An old question, but for anybody landing here... on Windows I use Ch shell standard edition, which include md5, sha1, wget, curl, etc.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux systems, the program is usually named `md5sum`.

On BSD systems, the program is usually named `md5`.

On Windows systems, aim users to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum

Note that the `md5sum` and `md5` utilities have a command-line option that can verify all the MD5 hashes listed in an MD5SUM file automatically:

```
sarnold@haig:~/bin$ md5sum * > /tmp/MD5SUM
sarnold@haig:~/bin$ md5sum -c /tmp/MD5SUM
aa-change: OK
aa-change.c: OK
briss: OK
mkvtom2ts: OK
muxer: OK
muxer_orig: OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Programming languages usually have a library to do this.

OS X has a command line utility 'md5'. Linux has something similar. For windows, no idea, but you can probably find something easily.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, if you install Cygwin, md5sum becomes available.